# How to manually insert ACL table's entry in CakePHP 2.2.1?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I know that I can put action as `$this->Auth->allow('');` for all user's roles but I want to  add action in the ACL tables and fetch action permission from ACL tables and also I’ve three group users 1 Admin, 2 Users, 3 Guest and I want to add permission for an action called "AutoCompleted" in the tables manually for all users. Tables are below :

acos, aros and aros_acos (the usual CakePHP tables)

Answer (score 1):

The user's roles uses the `aros_acos` table, and this is the structure:

[image: aros_acos structure]

To manually insert an user role in this table, you need first to know some info:

1. The ID of the action "AutoCompleted" (acos)
2. The ID of the user group you want to assign this new permission (aros)

If you open your `acos` table, you will see this:

[image: acos table data]

Somewhere in this table, you will find the "AutoCompleted" ID, which in this example is 35 (see image above).

Now, open the `aros` table, which have all the user groups info:

[image: aros table data]

Somewhere in this table, you will find the user group id, which in this example is 15 (see image above).

Ok, so this is all we have:

1. Action ID (aco_id): 35
2. User Group ID (aro_id): 15

With this information, you can now manually insert a new permission in the `aros_acos` table:

```
INSERT INTO  `sgc`.`aros_acos` (
    `id` ,
    `aro_id` ,
    `aco_id` ,
    `_create` ,
    `_read` ,
    `_update` ,
    `_delete`
)
VALUES (NULL ,  '15',  '35',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1')
```

The `_create`, `_read`, `_update`, `_delete` receives the value `1` because we want to allow the user to do this action.